# Can not add a nuget package in visual studio 2015 web api project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I am not able to add a simple nuget package in Visual Studio 2015 Web API project.

I have Visual Studio 2015 Professional Update 1.

Following are the steps I am following:

1. Created a new ASP .NET Web Application project with "Web API" template from ASP.NET 5 templates.
2. As soon as I get the project created my solution explorer show 2 DNX references. 
    (i) DNX 4.5.1
    (ii) DNX Core 5.0
3. Now I right click on project name and click "Manage Nuget Packages".
4. I search for JSON package and I see "Newtonsoft.Json" in the results. And I go ahead and select "Latest stable 8.0.2" version and hit install.

Result: Not able to add package:

And this is one of last few lines in the output window
     "Unable to locate Dependency Newtonsoft.Json >= 8.0.2"

Errors windows says something different"

Error   NU1001  The dependency Newtonsoft.Json >= 6.0.6 could not be resolved.

Would be great if someone can help.

FYI: my project.json looks like this:
[image]

Please let me know if there is some more info I should add, I can share all steps screen shots.

Comment: Did you build your project right after creation?

Comment: Yes, I built the project, still I was getting errors. But I got the problem resolved by deleting the Nuget.config file present at location %appdata%\NuGet. Now I have no idea how this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I also have been bangin' my head with this for 5 days already.

I have been trying to install the erroneous library using the nuget, both on console and the GUI. Did not work and it made me nuts and go wild. Only to find out, that the solution was to locate the library manually on your local drive located on your users folder, you should find a folder **/.dnx/packages**

Locate your library on that folder, adding it manually. I'm not sure if this is the case with you, but it worked for me.

Hope this helps.